# how to center text in the middle of the page

Tags: html, css, image, center

Wondering how a rotated text can be fixed in the center of the page?
Here is a **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kenhimself/0eefdLxn/)**, and I'm hoping I can accomplish this with CSS / html only.

Many thanks :)

**HTML**

```
<h1 class="main rotate">TEXT</h1>
```

**CSS**

```
h1 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.rotate {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 50%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 50%;
    -ms-transform-origin: 0 50%;
    -o-transform-origin: 0 50%;
    transform-origin: 0 50%;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(-50%, 50%);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(-50%, 50%);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(-50%, 50%);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(-50%, 50%);
    transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(-50%, 50%);
}
```

Comment: your text is already in the center !

Comment: @ZeRuBuES -- Not quite. It's not centered completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is to use good ol' `top`, `right`, `bottom`, `left` trick using `margin: auto` with the addition of `1em` `height` and `line-height`.  Like so:

```
h1 {
    ...

    /* new code */
    left:0;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    height: 1em;
    line-height: 1em;
    margin: auto;
}

.rotate {
    /* new code */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pqz0v71d/

Answer (score 1):

Interesting excercise, my approach here:

```css
h1 {
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50%;
  -o-transform-origin: 50%;
  transform-origin: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-90deg);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-90deg);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-90deg);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-90deg);
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
.centeredbox{
  position: fixed;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  z-index: 15;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -5px 0 0 -5px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="centeredbox"></div>
<h1 class="main rotate">TEXT</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your text is not centered because you are using the `h1` tag, which most browsers have built-in styles for it.

The text is properly centered if you change the tag to `div`.
[JSFiddler here](http://jsfiddle.net/4uqb3fLz/1/).

Comment: whether its h1 or div, that really shouldn't be an issue since I've given it properties that override the default h1 style. Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Answer (score 0):

this code below sweets your need

```
h1 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    margin:-302px 0 0 -34px;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 300ms ease;
    -moz-transition: opacity 300ms ease;
    transition: opacity 300ms ease;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
    -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
    -o-transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateZ(0);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uubzrew3/